# Client's method for channel subscribing

Tags: javascript, api, interface

I am writing an open-source application for real-time messaging in web. In my application clients from browser can subscribe on channels. But every channel belongs to a certain namespace which determines channel's settings:

```
client.subscribe('/football/news', function(message) {
    // message from channel received
});
```

where `football` is namespace name and `news` is channel name. `football` can be a default namespace for project and in this case we can write in this way:

```
client.subscribe('/news', function(message) {
    // message from channel received
});
```

i.e. without namespace name. This is how it works right now.

But my question is about `/` path separator. Is it ok? We need the way do separate namespace name and channel name. `/` usage was influenced by `Bayeux` protocol spec. But maybe it would be more simple and correct to write in such manner:

```
client.subscribe('football', 'news', function(message) {
    // message from channel received
});
```

or with default namespace:

```
client.subscribe(null, 'news', function(message) {
    // message from channel received
});
```

or even:

```
client.subscribe('news', function(message) {
    // message from channel received
});
```

I personally feel that the second way is better. But before refactoring I decided to ask for your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An opinion question, always tough to answer.

I like the first way better, 1 less parameter and it is easier to grok for me.

Incidentally, ABAP uses forward slashes for namespaces as well.

Comment: btw, I think using '\' makes creating full path harder for end user - we must properly concatenate strings - namespace and channel.

Comment: How about '/sports/football/news' ( 2 levels ), how would you do that with approach 2?

Comment: in my app only 1 level is allowed. I don't see any serious advantages in using hierarchy channels. Wildcards maybe? But are they really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

If you always have two levels, then passing two parameters has its advantages.

If the channels form an arbitrarily deep hierarchy, then a `/path/to/the/channel` makes more sense.